# When using remote docker interpreter, PyCharm takes a long time indexing $HOME/.cache/JetBrain/remote_sources

Tags: python, docker, indexing, pycharm

I have multiple pip libraries installed in the docker image which is used for the remote docker interperter, and the indexing takes **~5 mins**. As indexing usually behaves in PyCharm, it happens every time I open PyCharm and randomly while I am working, so I often cannot work because of it.
I can't seem to exclude this folder, as it is not in the interpreter paths.

How can I stop PyCharm from indexing  `$HOME/.cache/JetBrain/remote_sources`?
I'm using pycharm pro 2021.2.1 with a remote python 3.9.6 docker with a custom image containing  multiple pip packages.